# Bazel hazelcast remote cache

Tags: hazelcast, bazel

I'm trying to debug why the remote caching doesn't work for my use case.
I wanted to inspect the cache entries related to bazel, but realized that I don't really know and can't find what map names are used.
I found one **"hazelcast-build-cache"** - this seems to keep some of the build and test actions. I've set up a listener to see what gets put there, but I can't see any of the success actions.

For example,I run a test, and I want to verify that the success of this test gets cached remotely. I have no idea how to do this. I would either want to know how to find it out, or what map names I can inspect in hazelcast to find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazelcast Management Center can show you all the maps/caches that you create or get created in the cluster, how data is distributed etc. You can also make use of various types of listeners within Hazelcast: EntryListener, MapListener etc.

Take a look at documentation: 
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/manual/html-single/index.html#management-center

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/manual/html-single/index.html#distributed-events